# Error 2 error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'blitz/array.h': No such file or directory

Tags: c++

I am getting an error trying to use the Blitz package in Visual Studio for C++.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <blitz/array.h>
using namespace blitz;

int main() {
   Array<float,2> A(2,2), B(2,2), C(2,2);
   A = 1, 0, 2, 2;
   B = 0, 0, 7, 0;

   C = A + B;

   cout  << "C = " << C << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

I am receiving the following error.

> Error 2 error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'blitz/array.h': No such file or directory

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems pretty self-explanatory to me. It's looking for headers you include and it can't find that one. You might need to move the library to somewhere else or add an additional include directory to search (from the project properties).

Comment: Make sure you have that file in the correct location. Either use the full path like `#include "C:\folder\blitz\array.h"` or use relative path gymnastics `#include "..\..\blitz\array.h"` for example.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler cant find the file named blitz/array.h
Check that the Blitz installation path is in one of your included directories.

Looks like you are using Visual Studio, [MSDN explains how to add an include directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73f9s62w.aspx).

Different compilers have different options for adding a path. For gcc, [look at the Official GNU documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html).